# Rename a multi images upload

Tags: php

here is my problem i need to rename the images when someone upload it, i want to use date and time and to created the $datatime value and i dont know how to make it works can some tell me how to do it? any help much be appreciated... Much Thanks

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['action'])=='uploadfiles') {
$time = time();
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$datetime = "$time" . "$date";

$upload_directory   ='uploads/';  
$count_data         =count($_FILES['data']) ;
$upload             = $_FILES['data']['name'][$x].',';  

for($x=0;$x<$count_data;$x++) {
    $upload .= $_FILES['data']['name']["$x" . ""].',';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'][$x], $upload_directory . $_FILES['data']['name'][$x]); ##### upload into your directory     }

//echo "upload successfully..";
$con="INSERT INTO inmuebles (foto1) values ('$upload')";
$query=mysql_query($con); } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change here:

```
move_uploaded_file(
  $_FILES['data']['tmp_name'][$x],
  $upload_directory . $datetime . $_FILES['data']['name'][$x]
); ##### upload into your directory
```

Here the `$datetime` should be the string containing the timestamp.

Comment: This will obscure the file extension.

Comment: @theftprevention Will change. Please wait for an updated answer.

Comment: thank you guys it works now! :D @PraveenKumar and @ theftprevention much appreciated you help really (sorry for my bad english) :D

Comment: Hi bro when I save the link on the Database, if I upload 3 images, its show 2 empty links with the raname name I had created, i would like when users upload 3 images its generate Just the 3 url on DB, also I would like to save the first image on a diferent var ($foto), im will appreciate any hepl from you! thank you so much because I tried so many times and always the same results :(

Comment: @user2765552 Can you explain clearly? I will be able to help, but your query is not clear.

Comment: Sorry for my english @kumar... Well the problem is, if I upload 3 images, when I check in database its seem like I had upload 5 images... Also i would like to save one image on diferent $var

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES['data']['name'][$x], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$newname = $datetime . '.' . $ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'][$x],
                   $upload_directory . $newname);
```

This will **replace** the current filename, and maintain the extension of the originally uploaded file.

If you want to **maintain** the original filename and simply **append** the `datetime` to it, use the following:

```
$info = pathinfo($_FILES['data']['name'][$x]);
$ext = $info['extension'];
$name = $info['filename'];
$newname = $name . $datetime . '.' . $ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['data']['tmp_name'][$x],
                   $upload_directory . $newname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using date and time is a poor way to uniquely label anything because the limit of your fidelity is 1 item per second and computers are WAY faster than that, along with the fact more than 1 person could be using the upload at the same time.  Instead use something build for this such as UUID (aka GUIDs).  You can just use the  uniqid()  function in PHP which is very basic or if you read the comments somebody has written a UUID function (use version 5).

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php